# Where are update files stored in android?

Tags: updates, samsung-galaxy-s-4

I recently tried to update my Samsung galaxy S4 from ***Android Kitkat*** to ***Android Lolipop***.The process downloaded a large file ( Around 1.1 GB ).But the dowload **failed** when it was almost **99%** due to some unknown reason.However on checking the update again , it **restarted** the download from **0%**.
But i'cant download it anymore due to some other reason.I would like to know if it is possible to ***find & delete*** the downloaded file ( The files from 99% download ) ?

Is there any way to **continue** the process from the 99% ?

Any advice is appreciated.Thanks in advance.